# How can I access an environment parameter in the heading?

Tags: environments, koma-script

I'm using the scrartcl class and have defined an environment which takes a parameter. So far, so good. But the parameter should occur in the heading - how can I access it?

```
\documentclass[headsepline]{scrartcl}

\newenvironment{myenvironment}[1]{The parameter: #1}{}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenvironment}{myparameter}

\end{myenvironment}

\end{document}
```

The environment is semantically like a section, the parameter is a property which should show up in the heading of all pages where the current environment is. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `\markboth{}{} ` and `\markright{} ` is what is normally used. Markboth writes to both the left and right mark. Guess what the other one only do

Comment: Yes, but where? In the environment definition?

Comment: In the definition of your env

Comment: Yes. Sometimes it is too obvious. Thank you.